# How to install the Calibri font on Latex easily?

Tags: fonts, texmaker, mac, sans-serif

I'm using TexMaker on Mac and I'd like to find out how I could install the Calibri font (or other similar font like Open Sans for example) in the easiest possible way. I'm only familiar with the basic functions of Latex... 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "install" in the sentence  "I'd like to find out  how I could install the Calibri font". Is your objective to *make use* of Calibri in a LaTeX document, or is it to *obtain* the Calibri font file from some external source and to activate it on your computer system? Please advise.

Answer (score 7):

Calibri is a font created by Microsoft that's distributed with the Windows operating system (since about 2007) and with many Microsoft software products.

Assuming that Calibri is installed on your system, all you need to do to make use of it in your LaTeX document is to (a) compile the document under either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and (b) insert the following two instructions in the preamble of your document:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Calibri}
```

If you want to make Calibri the *main* text font of your document, change `\setsansfont{Calibri}` to `\setmainfont{Calibri}`.

[image]

Speaking for myself, I happen to quite like Calibri, in large part because it provides a true italic font face (as opposed to just a slanted version of the regular or "upright" font face). This is noticed most easily in the shapes of letters a, e, f, and g.

```
%% (To be compiled with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Calibri}
\newcommand\qbf{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\begin{document}
\textsf{\qbf}

\textit{\textsf{\qbf}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of fonts coming with your LaTeX distribution. You can check them here: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html or here: https://ctan.org/topic/font-sans

Open Sans should be already installed on your system, all you need to do is adding then following line to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
```

---

If you really, really want calibri, you have to jump through some hoops: Calibri is a font shipped with Microsoft Office, so you have to have at least one of the Office applications installed. If you have Word installed, go to `cd /Applications/Microsoft\ Word.app/Contents/Resources/Fonts` and copy the calibri fonts to your font folder, e.g. `~/Library/fonts`.